# Moving controls among tabpages

Tags: vb.net, controls, tabcontrol, tabpage

I'm trying to move 3 controls among 3 tabpages when the user is selecting a different tabpage. They're a toolsrtip control, a richtextbox control and a combobox control.

The richtextbox and combobox will be assigned new values for some of their properties depending on the tabpage selected, the toolstrip should be the same, but it's methods (it's a typical font style handling toolstrip) should be affecting the richtextbox that is visible on the current tabpage only.

Now, because changing the display value of a combobox also means that the richtextbox on the current tabpage will be assinged a new value for its text property, I didn't want to create like 3 comboboxes and 50 richtextboxes for every occasion. I want to create only one set of them and hold their values in some type of string collection before the uses raises an event, that is either change the combobox displayed item or changing the tabpage.

Not having done this before I read this
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?478602-2005-Move-controls-From-One-Tab-Page-To-Another which suggest to create a control for its occasion, which seems absurd to me...

My current situation is that I have the controls displaying at tabpage1 through designer and then I tried something like this

```
Private Sub TabPage_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabPage1.Enter, TabPage2.Enter, TabPage3.Enter
    Select Case DirectCast(sender, TabPage).Name

        Case "Tabpage1"
            TabPage1.Controls.Add(RichTextBox1)
            TabPage1.Controls.Add(ToolStrip1)
            TabPage1.Controls.Add(ComboBox1)

        Case "TabPage2"
            TabPage2.Controls.Add(RichTextBox1)
            TabPage2.Controls.Add(ToolStrip1)
            TabPage2.Controls.Add(ComboBox1)

        Case "TabPage3"
            TabPage3.Controls.Add(RichTextBox1)
            TabPage3.Controls.Add(ToolStrip1)
            TabPage3.Controls.Add(ComboBox1)

    End Select
End Sub
```

Now when changing tabs, controls appear on tabpage2 and tabpage3 but tabpage1 remains empty. I tried doing this at form load event

```
TabPage1.Controls.Add(RichTextBox1)
TabPage1.Controls.Add(ToolStrip1)
TabPage1.Controls.Add(ComboBox1)
```

but still tabpage1 remains empty when changing back to its view. I'm not sure what I'm trying is what I want to do, but I understand that for this approach I shouldn't use designer at all and instead create the controls only in code handling size and location myself. Please advice if there is a "right" way of doing this, mainly for keeping the code short and tidy. TIA.

ps.As I was writing this I realized that I could create only three of each control in designer for every tabpage and then handle the combobox change with the string collection way I had in mind. Seems sensible enough but I still wanna know about this, hence I'm still asking this question.

Comment: Should "Tabpage1 " have an uppercase "P" in your case statement, to match your TabPage1 name?

Comment: That was well spotted, I was looking for a typo, but because I was focus on the sorting number 1,2,3 I didn't notice :D

Comment: So obviously the controls appear now on the first tab (damn I checked 3 times before making this post and I didn't spot the typo) :P But I'm wondering what exactly happens when I'm adding the control at the tabpage, everytime that the enter event triggers? Is this the way to do it? I guess I'll find out while I'm progressing with my code. But if there is a better way please add it as an answer, or answer with an informative post about what happens with continuously adding the control. TIA

Comment: I think the entire strategy is a little strange. Would you consider testing to see if the control is on the tabpage before adding it?

Comment: I placed a counter for the first tab so it only runs the code to add the controls if the counter is < 0. As it runs when I enter the 1st tab a second time the controls are not there, so in theory it DOES move them among the tabs. Right now this is giving me such a headache because when I change tabs while my splitcontainer is collapsed, it messes with the controls widths somehow extending them beyond the form, and they get anchored there... anyway back to the topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution for moving your control as you progress between tabs
It does assume your control has already been created once.

```
Private Sub TabControl1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.Click

    Try

        Dim tabCtrl As TabControl = DirectCast(sender, TabControl)
        Dim tabPageItem As TabPage = tabCtrl.SelectedTab
        moveControl(MobileButton, tabPageItem)

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred:", ex.Message))

    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub moveControl(controlToMove As Control, newTab As TabPage)

    Dim findButton() As Control = newTab.Controls.Find(controlToMove.Name, True)

    If findButton.GetUpperBound(0) < 0 Then

        controlToMove.Parent = newTab

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That is a true moving of controls, compared to what I was trying...pff Thank you so much, this actually solved even the problems I had, which I describe above, where the collapsing of the container messed with the controls widths. Thank you for the assistance Andrew!